# Remove "Match Gantt Dates "- FSL

Tags: field-service-lightning, custom-permission, fsl

I want to hide this but I am not able to find the exact custom permission for this. Please help me out

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in [custom permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pfs_custom_permissions.htm&type=5) provided by Salesforce that allows you to control the visibility or behavior of the ‘Match Gantt Dates’ checkbox. Any customisation or control over its behavior would typically require custom CSS or JavaScript solutions.

You might want to log an Idea on Salesforce [Ideaexchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/) to have this implemented.